# ticket refreshment,circle,discount in java

Tags: java

In a multiplex theater, there is a discount scheme announced where one gets a 10% discount on the total cost of tickets when there is a bulk booking of more than 20 tickets, and a discount of 2% on the total cost of tickets if a special coupon card is submitted. Develop a program to find the total cost as per the scheme. The cost of the king class ticket is Rs.75 and queen class is Rs.150. Refreshments can also be opted by paying an additional of Rs. 50 per member.
Hint: k-king and q-queen and You have to book minimum of 5 tickets and maximum of 40 at a time. If fails display "Minimum of 5 and Maximum of 40 Tickets".  If circle is given a value other than 'k' or 'q' the output should be "Invalid Input".

The ticket cost should be printed exactly to two decimal places.

Sample Input 1:
Enter the no of ticket:35
Do you want refreshment:y
Do you have coupon code:y
Enter the circle:k

Sample Output 1:
Ticket cost:4065.25

Sample Input 2:
Enter the no of ticket:1
Sample Output 2:
Minimum of 5 and Maximum of 40 Tickets

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class CinemaTicket{
    private static DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         int no,refe,total =0;
         double cost,sum,sum1=0,sum2,sum3=0;
         String ref,co,circle;
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter the no of ticket:");
         no=s.nextInt();
         if(no>=5 && no<=40){

         System.out.print("Do you want refreshment:");
         ref=s.next();
         System.out.print("Do you have coupon code:");
         co=s.next();
         System.out.print("Enter the circle:");
         circle=s.next();
         if(circle.equals("k") || circle.equals("q")) {
         if(circle.equals("k")){
             total=no*75;
         } else if (circle.equals("q")){
             total=no*150;
         }
         //else{
          //   System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        // }
         //System.out.println(total);
         if(no>20){
             sum=((0.1)*total);
             sum1=total-sum;
             //System.out.println(sum1);
         }
         else{
             cost=total;
         }
             if(co.equals("y")){
                 sum2=((0.02)*sum1);
                 sum3=sum1-sum2;
                //System.out.println(sum3);
             }
             else{
                 cost=sum1;
             }
                 if(ref.equals("y")){
                     refe=no*50;
                     cost=sum3+refe;
                     System.out.println(cost);
                 }else{
                     cost=sum3;
                 }




            // System.out.println(cost);

             System.out.println("Ticket cost:" + df.format(cost));
         }

         else{
             System.out.println("Invalid Input");
         }}
         else{
             System.out.println("Minimum of 5 and Maximum of 40 Tickets");
         }

             }}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?  What are you stuck on?

Answer (score -1):

**> Find the executable code below -**

```
import java.util.*;

class CinemaTicket
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no of ticket:");
    int ticket = scn.nextInt();
    if(ticket>=5 && ticket<=40)
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want refreshment:");
        String refreshment = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Do you have coupon code:");
        String code = scn.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the circle:");
        String circle = scn.next();
        
        double cost = 0;
        switch(circle)
        {
            case "k":
                {
                    int value = 75;
                    cost = (ticket*value);
                    if(ticket>20)
                    {
                        cost = cost - (cost*.1);
                    }
                    if(code.equals("y"))
                    {
                        cost = cost - (cost*.02);
                    }
                    if(refreshment.equals("y"))
                    {
                        cost = cost + (50*ticket);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println("Ticket cost:"+ String.format("%.2f",cost));
                    
                    break;
                }
            case "q":
                {
                    int value = 150;
                    cost = ticket*value;
                    if(ticket>20)
                    {
                        cost = cost- (cost*.1);
                    }
                    if(code.equals("y"))
                    {
                        cost = cost-(cost*.02);
                    }
                    if(refreshment.equals("y"))
                    {
                        cost = cost+(50*ticket);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println("Ticket cost:"+ String.format("%.2f",cost));
                    break;
                }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Minimum of 5 and Maximum of 40 Tickets");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> You can use this code you will get expected output

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class Theater {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


double noTicket, refe, total = 0,total1=0;
double cost=0, sum, sum1, sum2, sum3=0;
String ref, coupon , circle;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the no of ticket:");
noTicket = s.nextInt();
if (noTicket < 5 || noTicket > 40) {
System.out.println("Minimum of 5 and Maximum of 40 tickets");
System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Do you want refreshment:");
ref = s.next();
System.out.println("Do you have a coupon code:");
coupon  = s.next();
System.out.println("Enter the circle:");
circle = s.next();
if (circle.equals ("k")) {
total = noTicket * 75;
} else if (circle.equals("q")) {
total = noTicket * 150;
} else {
System.out.println("Invalid Input");
}


/* for 10% percent discount */
if (noTicket > 20) {
sum = ((0.1) * total);
total = total - sum;
total1=total;

}
if (ref.equals("y")) {
refe = noTicket * 50;
total = total + refe;
}
if (coupon .equals("y")) {
sum2 = ((0.02) * total1);
total = total - sum2;
total1=total;

}
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println("Ticket cost:" + df.format(total));
}
}`
```